# Как сменить язык в Linux на alt+shift?

Tags: linux, mate, parrot-os

Всем привет. Я новичок в Linux, решил поставить дистрибутив parrot os с оболочкой MATE, и не знаю как менять язык на alt+shift. Как-то бесит каждый раз нажимать мышкой на кнопку смены языка. Кто знает как решить?

Comment: В MATE должны быть самые обычные настройки клавиатуры

Comment: `control center` - `keyboard` - `options` - .. [Настройка раскладки клавиатуры в Parrot OS](https://way23.ru/parrot_os_keyboard_layout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в настройки, раскладку и горячие клавиши (не помню точное расположение) и найди сочетание клавиш смены раскладки. Сам долго страдал, не знал как сделать, использовал арч с де кли, там вообще тяжко было)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].